# 'MyDatasourceObject' does not exist in the current context when report is loaded in C# application

Tags: fastreport

I created a report in the FastReport Community designer, where I set up a Data Source connection to select a product with a parameter, prod_id.

I added this resulting "product" as the Data source of my DataBand.
In my report I use this product to show it's properties in textfields, name, EAN...

Previewing the report works.

However, if I upload this report and load it in my dotnet application, I get the error:

```
    FastReport.Utils.CompilerException: (Text1): Error CS0103: The name 'product' does not exist in the current context
(Barcode1): Error CS0103: The name 'product' does not exist in the current context
(Text2): Error CS0103: The name 'product' does not exist in the current context
(Text3): Error CS0103: The name 'product' does not exist in the current context
(Text5): Error CS0103: The name 'product' does not exist in the current context

   at FastReport.Code.AssemblyDescriptor.InternalCompile()
   at FastReport.Code.AssemblyDescriptor.Compile()
   at FastReport.Report.Compile()
   at FastReport.Report.Prepare(Boolean append)
   at FastReport.Report.Prepare()
   at FastReportDemo.Program.Main(String[] args) in
```

My code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Request detected");

                        // Retrieve the productId parameter from the query string
                        string productIdStr = request.QueryString["prod_id"];
                        int productId;
                        if (!int.TryParse(productIdStr, out productId))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid prod_id.");
                            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                            response.Close();
                            continue;
                        }

                        Report report = new Report();

                        report.Load(@"templates/test.frx");

                        // Set the productId parameter in the report
                        report.SetParameterValue("prod_id", productId);

                        report.Prepare();

                        PDFSimpleExport pdfExport = new PDFSimpleExport();
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        pdfExport.Export(report, ms);

                        response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                        response.ContentLength64 = ms.Length;
                        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf");
                        ms.WriteTo(response.OutputStream);

                        Console.WriteLine("Report generated successfully!");
                        response.OutputStream.Flush();
```

I'm quite new to FastReport and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong, setting up this datasource in the report itself is enough, or isn't it? There is also a defaultvalue set for prod_id for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what was missing.

I had to install an additional package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastReport.Data.MsSql

And add following code to allow the connection to take place:

```
    using FastReport.Data;
//...

    FastReport.Utils.RegisteredObjects.AddConnection(typeof(MsSqlDataConnection));
```

In my report itself I had to create a report parameter and add it as an expression for my query parameter defined in my datasource selection.